# Obtaining very high loss during fine tuning of ResNetV2 in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet, transfer-learning

I am fine-tuning ResNetV2 model trained previously using transfer learning on 320 images from 40 classes. I am adding 1 class containing 8 images to the model and trying to retrain the model, but I am getting a very high loss value during training. I got a good accuracy(~91%) when training on 40 classes. Please help

```
base_model = models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/saved_model/resnetv2.h5')
base_model.trainable = True
preds=Dense(41,activation='softmax',name='main_output')(base_model.layers[-2].output) 
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,shear_range = 0.2,zoom_range = 0.2,horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,target_size = (224,224),batch_size = 2, class_mode = 'categorical')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,target_size = (224,224),batch_size = 2,class_mode = 'categorical')

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
training = model.fit_generator(training_set,validation_data=test_set,epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=1)
```

Comment: What is very high loss here?

Comment: around 200 with accuracy showing: 0.0000e+00